# Clean way to create column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My question is simple - I have the following table:

```
+----------+-------+------------+--------+
| industry | class | occupation | value  |
+----------+-------+------------+--------+
|      170 |     4 |       1000 |  123.3 |
|      180 |     7 |       3600 | 4543.8 |
|      570 |     5 |        990 |  657.4 |
+----------+-------+------------+--------+
```

I'd like to create a new column called "type". The value of this column is based on these multiple conditions

- Class = 7 : QWE
- Class = 8 : ASD
- Class = 1 or 2 : ZXC
- Class = 4, 5, or 6 AND Industry = 170-490 or 570-690 AND Occupation >=1000 : IOP
- Class = 4, 5, or 6 AND Industry = 170-490 or 570-690 AND Occupation between 10-3540 : JKL
- Anything else : BNM

The resulting table will look like this:

```
+----------+-------+------------+--------+------+
| industry | class | occupation | value  | type |
+----------+-------+------------+--------+------+
|      170 |     4 |       1000 |  123.3 | IOP  |
|      180 |     7 |       3600 | 4543.8 | QWE  |
|      570 |     5 |        990 |  657.4 | JKL  |
+----------+-------+------------+--------+------+
```

My first approach to this was basically creating multiple dataframes of each type using the dataframe query method. However, I found out about the numpy "where" method and I am currently using a nested version of that to create the "type" column in one step. However, I feel like it's un-readable and I can imagine a situation where there are even more conditions that would make this process look really messy. Is there a cleaner way of doing this? Maybe with a dictionary or something?

Comment: does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas

Comment: You should try `np.select`

Comment: Try defining a function which returns the appropriate label for each condition and use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`

Comment: You have overlapping conditions for IOP vs JKL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up your conditions and outputs and store in lists:

```
a = df['class'].eq(7)  
b = df['class'].eq(8)  
c = df['class'].isin([1,2])    
helper = df['class'].isin([4,5,6]) & (df.industry.isin(range(170, 491)) | df.industry.isin(range(570, 691)))
d =  helper & df.occupation.ge(1000)
e = helper & df.occupation.isin(range(10, 3541))

conds = [a, b, c, d, e]
outs = ['QWE', 'ASD', 'ZXC', 'IOP', 'JKL']
```

Use **`np.select`**.  Just note that you have overlapping conditions, so there is a possibility for ambiguity between `IOP` and `JKL`

```
df['out'] = np.select(conds, outs, default='BNM')

   industry  class  occupation   value  out
0       170      4        1000   123.3  IOP
1       180      7        3600  4543.8  QWE
2       570      5         990   657.4  JKL
```

Comment: np.select is exactly what I was looking for! Also, you're right about the overlapping conditions - the conditions are a bit more complex in my actual code but I just wanted to simplify it and get the idea across. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Just in the case you do have overlapping conditions, `np.select` will choose the first match it finds in your list of conditions.  Happy programming!